# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:Name [org.wso2.carbon.custom.ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT/HelloBean] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [ejb:]

Tags: java, ejb, jboss7.x, jndi

I'm trying to run ejb Helloworld program and my JNDI[1] but I’m getting bellow error[2] I’m running Jboss AS 7 final and AS output list[3]. anyone guide on this to me what my mistake?

[1]

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs","org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
return new InitialContext(prop);
```

[2]

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [org.wso2.carbon.custom.ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT/HelloBean] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [ejb:].
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:819)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:167)
at org.wso2.carbon.context.internal.CarbonContextDataHolder$CarbonInitialJNDIContext.lookup(CarbonContextDataHolder.java:705)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
at org.wso2.carbon.connector.EJBConnector.callEJB(EJBConnector.java:69)
at org.wso2.carbon.connector.EJBConnector.connect(EJBConnector.java:40)
at org.wso2.carbon.connector.core.AbstractConnector.mediate(AbstractConnector.java:32)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.ext.ClassMediator.mediate(ClassMediator.java:78)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.TemplateMediator.mediate(TemplateMediator.java:97)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.InvokeMediator.mediate(InvokeMediator.java:129)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.InvokeMediator.mediate(InvokeMediator.java:78)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:149)
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:185)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:317)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:149)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

[3]

```
java:global/org.wso2.carbon.custom.ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT/HelloBean!org.wso2.carbon.custom.ejb.HelloIF
java:app/org.wso2.carbon.custom.ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT/HelloBean!org.wso2.carbon.custom.ejb.HelloIF
java:module/HelloBean!org.wso2.carbon.custom.ejb.HelloIF
java:jboss/exported/org.wso2.carbon.custom.ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT/HelloBean!org.wso2.carbon.custom.ejb.HelloIF
java:global/org.wso2.carbon.custom.ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT/HelloBean
java:app/org.wso2.carbon.custom.ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT/HelloBean
java:module/HelloBean
```

Comment: Can you show a piece of code where you get ejb reference from JNDI?

Comment: i didn't change but it' working fine now, Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved this issue after long search.  this because of classloder issue in glassfish. so added a method to solve the classloding issue then its work fine.

```
 Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
    ClassLoader oldClassLoader = currentThread.getContextClassLoader();
    try {
        //switching the classloader to prevent class loading glassfish classloading issues
        currentThread.setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
        //method to run
        callEJBStateful(messageContext);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        handleException("Error calling EJB Service from EJBConnector", e, messageContext);
    } finally {
        if (oldClassLoader != null) {
            //resetting the classloader
            currentThread.setContextClassLoader(oldClassLoader);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The JNDI address you should look up is

```
java:app/org.wso2.carbon.custom.ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT/HelloBean
```

The `java:app` [specifies the app namespace](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/JNDI+Reference?_sscc=t), so this assumes you're accessing this bean from the same app the bean is in.